# How does the delay function in Kotlin internally work?

Tags: asynchronous, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have been trying to understand how Kotlin coroutines work and I came across the `delay` function.

My understanding of this works is,

- `delay` suspends the current thread, where the thread, unlike `sleep`, does not consume CPU cycles and is freed to execute other tasks.
- How this works is that the code after the delay function is captured as a lambda(Continuation) and can be executed after the given time period by a different thread.
- The implementation seems similar to Javascript's execution model, where the `delay` function causes the continuation to be stored on some kind of a task queue and releases the current thread. After the specified time is elapsed, this task is scheduled on an available thread.

Is my understanding correct?
Also, is there a relation between the thread that calls `delay` and the thread that executes the code following the call to `delay`.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're interested how coroutines work, [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines/blob/master/kotlin-coroutines-informal.md) is a good read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Your understanding is correct. The difference between JS and Kotlin is that the task queue that is used to execute the continuation can be customized by the programmer via `CoroutineDispatcher`. In general, there is no relation between the thread that calls `delay` and the thread where continuation is scheduled for resume. It is determined by two factors:

- If the coroutine uses the `Unconfined` dispatcher, then the thread where the continuation is resumed is some system timer thread used internally in the implementation of `delay`. You can write your own version of `delay` that resumes `Unconfined` continuations on the thread of your choice.
- If the coroutine uses some confined dispatcher, then it resumes on the thread or a pool of threads defined by that dispatcher. A number of dispatchers are provided out of the box. For example, in Android using the `UI` dispatcher, the coroutine is going to be always resumed on the Android `UI` thread. In general, in Kotlin/JVM you can take any `Executor` and convert it to `CoroutineDispatcher` using `asCoroutineDispatcher` extension.